# How to catch post/get variables with Powershell httpListener?

Tags: powershell, http-post, http-get, httplistener

I want to know how to catch url vars with powershell system.net.HttpListener
Thanks

```
$listener = New-Object system.net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
$listener.Start()
$context = $listener.GetContext() # block
$request = $context.Request
$response = $context.Response
# $var = read post/get var
$page = Get-Content -Path C:\play.html -Raw
$page = $page.Replace('%VAR%',$var)
$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($page)
$response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
$output = $response.OutputStream
$output.Write($buffer,0,$buffer.Length)
$output.Close()
$listener.Stop()
```

Comment: Umm... that looks to me like you're trying to re-invent [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) in PowerShell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers They said the same thing about Javascript once upon a time....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method header is GET then use the QueryString property to get the query parameters.  If the method  header is POST then check HasEntityBody property and if that is true, read the POST data from the body using the InputSteam property.